# 1-form on the Riemannian manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $\omega$ a 1-form on a riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, and for a point $x\in M$, there is a notation: $|\omega_x|_g$, what does $|\omega_x|_g$ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the norm of the linear functional $\omega_x$ with respect to the scalar product induced on the cotangent bundle by the Riemannian metric. E.g. in coordinates, 
$$|\omega_x|^2= \sum_{i,j} g^{ij}(x)\omega_i(x) \omega_j(x)$$
where, in commonly used notation, $(g^{ij})$ is the inverse of $(g_{ij})$

Comment: What is $\omega_i(x)$?

Comment: @Antoine The $i$-th component of the differential form $\omega$ in the coordinate system of choice, at $x$.

Comment: For example, in the local coordinate, $\omega_x=\sum \omega_i(x)dx_i$. Is it like this?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The convention is, however, to write $dx^i$ instead of $dx_i$, so that the summation convention applies.

Comment: Thanks. I have an another related question: let $\omega_x=d_xf$, $f:M\to M$, how to write $|d_xf|$?

Comment: Just use $\omega_i(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$(x)